# Spam filtering based on average ascii score

Tags: spam, filter, exchangeonline

I'm trying to come up with a new spam filter based on what has been coming through our filter lately.  A lot of the messages have subject lines like: "Re: ᴢᴀɴᴛᴀᴄ 【ʜᴀs】 ʙᴇᴇɴ ʟɪɴᴋᴇᴅ 【ᴛo】 ᴄᴀɴᴄᴇʀ" where most of the text isn't actually the standard ascii 1 - 128 range but uses Unicode to simulate the look of the characters.  I know in PowerShell I can create a simple script to do the detection but I want it to run on Exchange instead.

```
$QuarantineMessage = Get-QuarantineMessage -SenderAddress *
(([int[]][char[]]$QuarantineMessage.Subject) | Measure-Object -Average).Average
```

I just want to tag messages that have the average of 128 or more.  I know the script above is for the Quarantine messages but I'm not sure how to catch incoming messages.  Either my Google-fu is failing me or it doesn't look like there is a widely accepted answer to this.  Is there a built in function for O365 that does this?

Answer (score -1):

You could Spam Filtering with Exchange Online Mail Flow Rules, like this:
[image]

For more details: [Use mail flow rules to filter bulk email in EOP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-transport-rules-to-configure-bulk-email-filtering?view=o365-worldwide) and [Better Spam Filtering with Exchange Online Mail Flow Rules](https://practical365.com/exchange-online/better-spam-filtering-mail-flow-rules/)